# Recover data from broken wd hard disk by replacing the head

Tags: linux, unix, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, wd

I have a broken wd hard disk, see this link for the detail status:

[How to use dd to backup "WD My Passport" on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/1742922/how-to-use-dd-to-backup-wd-my-passport-on-ubuntu)

Because it is not allowed to ask more than one question in the same post, so I ask this new question in this new post.

In order to `recover the data` from the above hard disk, I want to disassemble a `good hard disk head` from other `good wd hard disk` (also usb 3.0 and 1tb capacity, but made in different recent year), and then replace the `bad hard disk head` in the above mentioned `broken wd hard disk`.

Is this possibile?
Please help, thanks.

**Update:**

I can hear this from the broken wd hard disk when connected to the usb:

```
(1) start spinning and then beep beep (2 times),
(2) start spinning around 3 seconds (normal spinning)
(3) beep, beep, beep, beep (4 times)
(4) beep, beep, beep, beep (4 times)
(5) beep, beep, beep, beep (4 times)
(6) beep, beep, beep, beep (4 times)
(7) stop spining, and then no any sound and wait for around 5 seconds
(8) repeat the (2) to (8) over and over again if not disconnect from the usb
```

I think it is related to the head.

Comment: If you want to work on the innards of a HDD with confidence, you need a cleanroom (a dust-free environment).

Comment: @DanielB - you need a clean room to even open it. You need the hands of a brain surgeon to do anything more than take the lid off without damaging anything.

Comment: You can't. But you may try. Asking such question automatically means you dont have knowledge, tools, experience to acomplish this task

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Kpv2h-95AR0

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2019/12/24/hard-drive-data-recovery-why-not-diy/

Comment: https://www.overclockers.com/do-it-yourself-hard-disk-repair

Comment: Did you even try researching this before asking?

Comment: I have added more information at the end of the post, please help to check the updated post, thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/964463/western-digital-my-passport-beeps

Answer (score 6):

*"I want to disassemble…"* No, you don't. This is not a DIY job. Not in the slightest.

Open the drive at all, you may as well just throw it in the bin. Take it to a professional data recovery service.

<sup>Your previous QA mentions shucking the actual drive from its enclosure. This is an entirely different issue.</sup>

*After comments*
Even if you could find an *identical drive* [which you won't after 10 years; you'd have difficulty ensuring two identical enclosures bought at the same time would have identical drives inside] that would only be the start of your nightmares.
These things are assembled by microscopically nanometre accurate machines in million-dollar industrial clean rooms. One tiny mis-alignment or one speck of dust & your drive is toast.
"It's worse than that, it's dead Jim"

Comment: I have added more information at the end of the post, please help to check the updated post, thanks.

Comment: If the drive is physically damaged/broken, there is no way to DIY take it apart to fix it. It really is a "no user-serviceable parts inside" device.

Comment: I want to give it a try to replace the bad head with a good head (buy a new wd hard disk and then get the good head from it), but I'm worry about the data.

Comment: You cant just install arm with heads from other disk. Even with the same model it may not work at all

Comment: You need at least **same model of hdd manufactured at same time** so parts be physically exchangeble

Comment: The broken wd hdd was made in ten years ago. I can only buy a new one (same usb , same capacity, same my passport) made in this year.

Comment: @stackbiz If you manage to position new heads on the disk (unlikely), make sure this is done in a [clean room](https://www.cleanairproducts.com/resources/industry-standards/iso5) environment or you'll likely have an immediate head crash. Think HEPA filters on steroids with complete air replacement every few minutes.